# Update image file in django static files

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-channels

I'm processing video, then saving each frame as an image in my static folder. Every new image frame overwrites the previous one in the static file directory. The frames come at a pace of 1 per 5 seconds or so.

I want to show the frame images on my html file.

`<img src='../static/frame.jpg' id="image" width="300" height="200">`

But it isn't working. It keeps loading the version of the image that was used when it compiled.

It only updates when I refresh the page.

How can I avoid this?

This is the code that I'm using in javascript. Every time I get a websocket message, it should update. I get one every 5 seconds.

```
socket.onmessage = function(e){

   var recData=JSON.parse(e.data);

   image.setAttribute('src', '../static/frame2.jpg');

   (...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image is being cached by browser ( which is default expected behavior)

To say to your browser not to cache it you could add [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#Examples) header like in example, or implement [ETag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag)

Bit more hack of a solution (this would fill your browser cache unecessary) would be to add randomized number/datetime in get request

```
image.setAttribute('src', '../static/frame2.jpg?' + new Date().getTime());
```